# Proof from Navi about us returning to Eretz Yisrael

Tags: faith-bitachon-emunah

There is a proof given for Judaism from the fact that we returned to Eretz Yisrael, and that was so unlikely, so therefore this proves that the Torah is true. But how do we know if this occurrence is just that *some* prophecies would be expected to be fulfilled, since there has been so many prophets and prophecies throughout the world?

Why isn't it possible that this was just fulfilled by chance because certain prophecies would be likely to come true out of the millions of prophets and prophecies that have happened throughout the history of the world?

Comment: Welcome to MY Binyamin, thanks for the question. Could you clarify where you heard this proof? A link or quote?

Comment: That's literally what "so unlikely" means.

Comment: One would expect that anyone offering up the idea that our return to the Land of Israel is evidence of the Torah's truth, did not intend to suggest it as a formal "proof"

Comment: @DoubleAA What do you mean?

Comment: @Binyamin "unlikely" means it's logically possible just unlikely. You haven't discovered anything new by pointing out it's not logically impossible.

Comment: @DoubleAA But why is it unlikely, it likely since there were so many prophets throughout the history of the world?

Comment: @DoubleAA (my previous message)^?

Answer (score 2):

In truth I don't think you could "prove" anything true based off of one prophecy alone. Even if the prophet said the exact year, you could still argue it was chance, or self fulfilling prophecy....

I do think that being correct again and again and again, like Moses constantly warning and controlling the plagues etc... is a good "argument" or "proof".

If it was one prophecy I think you would be right, but numerous prophecies came true again and again. It is interesting to consider the rules for what undermines or legitimizes someone as a prophet and just because they can perform a "miracle" (wonder) is not enough, so even the Torah would agree that things can happen out of mere coincidence, the question is when is something not coincidental. Nowadays we call that statistical significance.

I think Hashem does leave open the room for doubt intentionally; otherwise, our free choice would be minimized. See Daat Tvunos (Chelek B, Chapter 1) that this is a prime part of our existence is to choose to do Mitzvot. You must decide and not have things proven beyond doubt, but there are extremely good arguments for Prophecy, its accuracy and our connection to Hashem. As a package with all the arguments, I find it very moving and hard not to believe.

Comment: Nice one, bringing the point about not relying on the miracles of prophets, and the point about free will. My only question is your point about "self fulfilling" and "exact date" - I'm not sure how those can go together?

Comment: @msj121 But wouldn't it be likely among all the prophets of the world that at least one would have everything they said come true?

Comment: @Binyamin No.... This would depend on many things... 1). What was said 2). How many things were said 3). The timeline given for an event etc... An infinite monkey scenario ONLY works because of INFINITY, which does not occur in the real world. Yes, random guesses will be "bound" to happen, but the more unlikely and the shorter time span makes this more impossible. So a claim about returning to Eretz Yisrael nowadays as a proof, less convincing then a 70 year prophecy for the second temple. But that doesn't mean Israel's return is no proof/no value.

Comment: @Binyamin I certainly wouldn't stake my whole belief in a religion on return to Eretz Yisrael, but there are few people this has happened to (if any)? Especially being away for so long. So here the "time" adds and subtracts to the miracle. The longer the jews exist outside of a country, the more miraculous their existence is, but the more one can rationalize eventually they would return. However, has a nation existed in exile so long to be able to return? There might be a reason there is only one nation... That being said I prefer other arguments myself. But this one does have value

Comment: I'd actually be curious if another nation can make this claim... keep in mind the types of exile too.

Comment: @RabbiKaii I only mean it could be argued that if the Jews would return at a specific year, well perhaps, everyone would prepare and even go to war because they believe it will come true and so it does. You are correct that if it happened on its own this would make self-fulfilling harder to understand. But I am sure there would be arguments to be made. But yes, an exact time increases the likelihood of divine providence imo, I just mean that people will likely still argue.

Comment: @msj121 gotcha. Now I question infinite monkey scenario and infinity. Sorry for being pedantic, if you don't literally mean "infinite", but because of the anthropic argument it might be prudent to be exact.

Comment: @RabbiKaii well an infinite amount of prophecies to happen tomorrow from ranging from mundane to miraculous will certainly have a correct prophecy. Simply because by definition every possible outcome including me going to the store is predicted. But my point is that in reality there is no such case in the real world, also in regard to prophecy the # of claims vs # of being correct is also important. And of course as mentioned the immediacy of said claims.